# Issue while setting value to tkinter Entry widget within for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm trying to design small tkinter window with range of 5 entry widget (both sides) using a for loop just like the following image.

[image]

Now my requirement is to type some value in the left side widget and it should automatically display on the right side while giving the **Tab** key. I tried the bind method using lambda and got the value. but I wonder how to set the value on each and every respective widget.

**MY CODE**

```
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()
num = 5

def my_funct(var):
    e.set(var)

r=0
for y in range(num):
    e = tk.StringVar()

    y = tk.Entry(root)
    y.bind("<Tab>", lambda event, y=y:my_funct(y.get()))
    y.grid(row=r, column=1)

    z = tk.Entry(root, textvariable=e)
    z.grid(row=r, column=2)
    r +=1

root.mainloop()
```

The Result I get is like the below image. Can someone help me out with my code to achieve what I expect?

[image]

As you can find out the value is displaying only in last widget for each and every Tab key. Can someone help me out solving this issue, please explain me how to achieve my required output.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem stems from fact that you reassign your `StringVar` each time, so `e` is always the last created one. You need a structure to hold those things, for example - a [`dict`](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict) with `{entry:variable}` pair.

Here's a snippet:

```
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()
num = 5

pairs = {}

def my_funct(entry):
    var = pairs.get(entry)
    if var is not None:
        var.set(entry.get())

# r = 0
for _ in range(num):
    e = tk.StringVar()

    y = tk.Entry(root)
    y.bind("<Tab>", lambda event, y=y:my_funct(y))
    y.grid(row=_, column=1)

    z = tk.Entry(root, textvariable=e)
    z.grid(row=_, column=2)
    # r +=1

    pairs.update({y:e})

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Ya it works good as I expected Thanks a lot for the answer. I'll choose this one. By the way I would appreciate if you tell me how to clear the widget at once using `delete(0,END)` method. since its in for loop which is confusing me a lot

Comment: @Sundararajan, [Take a look](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/entry.htm#Tkinter.Entry.delete-method) over effbot.org site. But in your case you can set a `textvariable` to `''` with `var.set('')`, just create a new function with same fashion as `my_funct`. It's also described [here](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/variable.htm). Anyway, it's not completely clear for what you're ask - feel free to update your question if you're stuck.