# How to make several variables in for to access them

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, variables, tkinter

I tried to create a matrix of checkbuttons and then access all the checkbuttons, but the answer is always 0.

```
x = dict()
var = dict()
for i in range(1, ex +1):
    for j in range(1, ey +1):
        Label(root, text=i, bg="#B8B8B8").place(x=i*25+ 3, y=10)
        Label(root, text=j, bg="#B8B8B8").place(x=10, y=j*25+ 3)
        var[i, j] = IntVar()
        x[i,j] = var[i, j].get()
        Checkbutton(root, bg="#B8B8B8", variable=var[i,j]).place(x=i*25, y=j*25)

Button(root, text="click", command=lambda: print(x[1, 1]) ).pack()
```

Comment: You're setting `x[i,j]` before the user has had a chance to check the buttons.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python Tkinter: How to config a button that was generated in a loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44588154/python-tkinter-how-to-config-a-button-that-was-generated-in-a-loop)

Comment: You should use `var[1, 1].get()` instead of `x[1, 1]`.  Basically `x` is useless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the provided code tries to access the value of the checkbuttons before they have been clicked, it has a problem. x[i,j] = var[i,j] is the line.All the entries in the x dictionary are set to 0 since get() is called before any of the checkbuttons are selected. You can change the lambda function in the Button widget to cycle through every checkbox and output its value in order to access the checkbuttons' values after they have been clicked. Here's an illustration:

```
Button(root, text="click", command=lambda: print({(i, j): var[i, j].get() 
for i in range(1, ex+1) for j in range(1, ey+1)})).pack()
```

Comment: thank you so much, also,could you please write it as a function.